# make a https get request in linux based on openssl

Tags: c, linux, https, openssl

guys.
I want to create a https get request on linux with openssl. I made the code from google and my mind. after i run the code,there is something happened, i think the RecvPacket() function has problem,but i do not know how to fix, please tell me how to fix it.
the website where i want to get is https://git.20202060.xyz.it just has a jpg file,what i want to do is download the picture to local file,but now i even can not get the https response,the i could not cut the picture out.
here is code.

```
SSL *ssl;
int sock;

int RecvPacket()
{
    int len = 1024;
    char buf[100000] = {'\0'};
    if (SSL_read(ssl, buf, 1024) > 0)
    {
        printf("Receiving . . . .\n");
        while (len = 1024)
        {
            // len = SSL_read(ssl, buf, 1024);
            len = SSL_read(ssl, buf, 1024);
            buf[len] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buf);
            if (len < 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (len < 0)
    {
        int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, len);
        if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
            return 0;
        if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
            return 0;
        if (err == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN || err == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL || err == SSL_ERROR_SSL)
            return -1;
    }
}

int SendPacket(const char *buf)
{
    int len = SSL_write(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (len > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Writing . . . . \n");
    }
    if (len < 0)
    {
        int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, len);
        switch (err)
        {
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
            printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE\n");
            return 0;
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
            printf("SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ\n");
            return 0;
        case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
            printf("SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN\n");
        case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
            printf("SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL\n");
        case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
            printf("SSL_ERROR_SSL\n");
        default:
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        printf("Error creating socket.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("119.28.113.108"); // address of 20202060.xyz
    sa.sin_port = htons(443);
    socklen_t socklen = sizeof(sa);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, socklen))
    {
        printf("Error connecting to server.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //openssl initialize
    SSL_library_init();
    SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

    if (!ssl)
    {
        printf("Error creating SSL.\n");
        log_ssl();
        return -1;
    }
    //creat an ssl connection and attach it to the socket
    sock = SSL_get_fd(ssl);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
    SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);
    int err = SSL_connect(ssl);
    if (err != 1)
    {
        printf("Error creating SSL connection.  err=%x\n", err);
        log_ssl();
        fflush(stdout);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("SSL connection using %s\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));

    char request[1024] = {'\0'};
    // char *request_test = "Get /dog.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)\r\nHost:https://20202060.xyz\r\nConnection: Close\r\n";
    char host[100] = "https://git.20202060.xyz";
    // char ip[30] = "119.28.113.108";
    sprintf(request,
            "GET /dog.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            "Host: %s\r\n"
            "Accept: */*\r\n"
            "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0\r\n"
            "Connection: Close\r\n",
            host);
    SendPacket(request);
    RecvPacket();

    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use libcurl to do it.

Comment: oh,man, my boss asked me to do this with openssl.